# Data binding issue with Angular JS and Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am unable to change scope values using angular js when using bootstrap modal. Basically I am calling function to open modal that I store in controller.js file and then I am trying to amend scope values and display them in modal dialog box.

I added click event to one of my js components.

```
eventClick: function(event, element) {
    var $scope = angular.element("#eRotaController").scope();
    $scope.OpenModal("addEventModal", false, event);
}
```

Part of html element (modal dialog):

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">{{misc.modalTitles}}</h4>
</div>
```

Finally OpenModal function and variables

```
// Variables
$scope.misc = {
    modalTitle: "",
    showRemoveEvent : false
};

$scope.OpenModal = function (modal, isNew, event)
{
    if (isNew) {
        $scope.misc.modalTitle = "Add new Event";
    }
    else{
        $scope.misc.modalTitle = "Update event for: " + event.title;
        $scope.misc.showRemoveEvent = true;
        console.log($scope);
    }

    $("#" + modal).modal('show');
}
```

When I update modalTitle for instance inside OpenModal function it does not reflect any changes when opening modal.

I created simpler example to find out if it's modal issue and turns out it's not.

Quick test that I have added :

```
<button ng-click="OpenModal2()"></button>
{{misc.showRemoveEvent}}


$scope.OpenModal2 = function()
{
    $scope.misc.modalTitle = "Update event for: " + event.title;
    $scope.misc.showRemoveEvent = true;
}
```

**That works fine.**

So it works correctly when method is called directly from html element but fail when called from js using reference to controller :

```
 var $scope = angular.element("#eRotaController").scope();

 $scope.OpenModal("addEventModal", false, event);
```

**Does not work**

Comment: Actually modal bootstrap got nothing do to with it. I tried to change scope value inside OpenModal and still does not work.

Comment: I highly advice you to use [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) instead of regular bootstrap, it's bootstrap implemented in angular (keeps your code clean with directives etc)

Comment: Thanks Martijn, but bootstrap is not the issue here after further investigation. Basically the function I called from js not directly from DOM is updating scope values but then it's not reflecting the changes on DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
eventClick: function(event, element) {
    var $scope = angular.element("#eRotaController").scope();
    $scope.$apply(function (){
         $scope.OpenModal("addEventModal", false, event);
    })
},
```

If eventClick is a function outside of angular context then the above code may work.

Comment: Thank you! You sir deserved medal of awesomeness.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$uibModal` - [$uibModal documation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), it goes like:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;
  //open modal
  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
  };

});
```